# Facebook rss feed does not work for public

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rss

(1) Using Graph API

I followed [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed) to get feed for public.

```
Bundle param = new Bundle();
        param.putString("limit", "500");
        new Request(session, "/me/feed", param, HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        feedJson = response.getGraphObject()
                                .getInnerJSONObject().toString();
                        }
                }).executeAsync();
```

After parsing **feedJson** from according to above code, i get post's url and other stuff but that url is not working for public like if i try to access that link from another fb account then it denied to access. What to do..??

(2) Using older way

And another way to access feed is like

i) https://graph.facebook.com/[page or account name for which you want to get feed]

you get **id** for that page or account and then

ii) https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id= [id of your page or account]&format=rss20

then hit enter it gives like **Facebook Syndication Error**- SyndicationErrorFeed

What to do..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using the API directly (which will need you to supply an access token for a user who's able to access that content) you won't be able to access the feed of a page which is restricted.
 so please get id is Invalid.

my code is successfully so please try this.

```
// Class with extends AsyncTask class
    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Content;
        private String Error = null;
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        // Call after onPreExecute method
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                // Server url call by GET method
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

                // Log.e("Content", "" + Content);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                cancel(true);
                Log.e("ClientProtocolException", "" + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                cancel(true);
                Log.e("IOException", "" + e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

            Dialog.dismiss();
            socialfeedList = new ArrayList<SocialfeedDataset>();

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Content.toString());
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("entries");
                Log.e("jsonArray", "" + jsonArray.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    String title = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                            .optString("title");
                    Log.e("title", "" + title);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

just Pass your url as perameter:

```
new LongOperation().execute(Constant.Facebook_Feed);
```

Comment: My token is this : CAAGMU1IJVU4BAOWtsIMXGHygWMNW9f2d26ev9evYKCMxSXhDAoY7Y9yevYkNAWEpJgMESKAdFiuP6R3FwPLnO9g4O7GJvByjtE3fu3E09GtmAcQKHvvc5PAmV7rUjWAnF7joOHU02zO7klPuse3GYC0gBggFP2l5MwSVyWhGeUvxrE3JGhX1PHVFpsuTloiwHOKLHrgK7xERg47O

and i hit this url : https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=CAAGMU1IJVU4BAOWtsIMXGHygWMNW9f2d26ev9evYKCMxSXhDAoY7Y9yevYkNAWEpJgMESKAdFiuP6R3FwPLnO9g4O7GJvByjtE3fu3E09GtmAcQKHvvc5PAmV7rUjWAnF7joOHU02zO7klPuse3GYC0gBggFP2l5MwSVyWhGeUvxrE3JGhX1PHVFpsuTloiwHOKLHrgK7xERg47O&format=rss20

but it did not work...it redirect to facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

I think Facebook RSS feeds are not available for private accounts. Public accounts that anyone can access without logging in have RSS accounts.

Comment: Ya i will try to make my account public but it did not work any other way...??

Comment: For protected accounts, I guess you will have to use Facebook API and a Java wrapper for it. I set mine to public or less than 13 years and the feeds works.

Comment: I have used Sarah Palin's Facebook feed and it works. Try with
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=24718773587

Comment: Do you know how to set account privacy to public or less than 13 years  through programmatically...??

Comment: Ha! You are processing the RSS feed. You are not processing Facebook API! You need to go to the Facebook page and change the setting manually. If it is another person's Facebook account, then you need to use Facebook API and its Java wrapper. You also need to get that person to add your account as a friend who can read the feed. Or, get your app registered with that person's account.